# General Compilation Problems VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm running VS2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RMTRel

I've noticed problems compiling VB.NET application.  When I "rebuild" the solution it reports the build was successful.  When I then click the run icon to begin debugging, then the compiler will report build errors(often related to referenced projects).  I've confirmed all the projects are targeting the same framework and after an undeterministic number of times repeating the same steps, it will eventually compile.  This seems consistent enough to me with other code bases to believe that it's a problem with VS.  Anyone have any thoughts that might help improve my experience?

Comment: Document the errors, it is just guessing without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also check your configuration manager - probably some of projects are disabled for building in current build plan.

Answer (score 0):

is this a rather large solution? If so, the order of build may be out of whack and the way to solve that is to set the build order of the projects to make sure all of the dependent projects are built first.

One common reason is circular references. You cannot do this in a pair of projects, but it can be done if you cobble together a long string of projects. The way to catch this is a dependency mapping tool with a visual representation of dependencies. You will see the items that refer back up to the top.